# Multiple Assignment syntax

Tags: c#, .net

Ive seen the following syntax in a couple of code samples, it looks pretty obvious, but not in the context that i saw it in, 
so can someone confirm

```
var x = 1
var y = 2
var z = 3

x = y = z
```

so in essence does this mean that 
x and y both equal z?

tried to google this, and couldn't find the syntax, also looked in murach .net books with no luck

Comment: Yea i just tested it and all the variables were 3 after hitting that.

Comment: Why don't you just test ? By the way it's quite usefull when your want for example to put the same text in various labels/textboxes... or anytime you want to spare some lines of code :-)

Comment: In the future, I would encourage you to simply run your program and find out :)

Comment: apologies, i had ran it, but the context that it was in within the sample code id seen, didn't make sense, was after confirmation which you all have done. Thank you for the fast responses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [assignment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) returns the value being assigned as it's result

> The assignment operator (=) stores the value of its right-hand operand in the storage location, property, or indexer denoted by its left-hand operand and *returns the value as its result*.

So

```
x = y = z;
```

Is parsed as

```
x = (y = z);
```

And this is equivalent to

```
y = z;
x = y;
```

In the end, `x`, and `y` are assigned the same value as `z` (in this case, `3`).

Comment: And that means both x and y are equal to z

Comment: @AD.Net No, not strictly speaking, due to the exact semantics.  If an implicit conversion operator is run when assigning `z` to `y`, the converted value is assigned to `x`, even if no implicit conversion operator would be run when assigning `z` to `x` directly.

Comment: @Servy Yes, you're right. `int x = 1; int? y = 2; int z = 3; x = (y = z);` produces "*Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*", but it's totally happy with `int x = 1; int y = 2; int? z = 3; x = (y = (int)z);`. I hadn't considered this case before.

Answer (score 1):

This will indeed set x and y to the value of z, however to see why you can parenthesize the expression:

```
x = (y = z);
```

In this case the `y = z` expression will return the new value for y (in this case 3), and set x to that value.

This works for very long expressions too:

```
x = y = z = a = b
x = (y = (z = (a = b)))
```

Where x, y, z and a will be set to the value of b.

EDIT:

Also remember the order of precedence of operators when using this method of reading into a long expression, while its not a good practice to create huge chained statements you do sometimes see it in code online, another (and better) way you can use to read confusing statements like this is to think of the syntax tree that is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Ehm, yes that is correct :).

x, y and x will all be 3 as you can assign values like that.

you can make the chain as long as you like too.

```
a = b = c = d;
```

all preceding values would be the value of `d`